# ViewPager Fragment aimation - Get active fragment context

Tags: java, android

I have 3 fragments im my pager, and I want to animate TextViews in fragment when I swipe to that fragment.

In my main Activity I have listener on PageSelected and I get current fragment that is active, but main problem is here:

Animaton requires context, and I can't get Context of that fragment on which I'm going to animate.

Slide Activity:

```
    else if (position == 1 && lastPosition==2){
contentTextView2.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(FragmentB.context, R.anim.slide_in_right));
    }
```

I set Fragment Context in Fragment B but I getting null exception, here is how i set that in Fragment B

FragmentB:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    public static Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_b,container,false);
        context = container.getContext();
        return v;
    }
```

Adapter is standard adapter for pager.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [ViewPager.PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer).

[Here](https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4#.begleifl0) is a good tutorial from Chris Basha for animating Views.